# Before undelete trigger event

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to Salesforce and learning Trigger.

In trigger, we do have two types before, after and they have DML options like insert, update, delete and undelete.

But there is no before undelete event. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In reality the record is available in the recycle bin, but the field isDeleted of this record is set to True hence, the before undelete trigger wouldn’t be able to see the records(values) that it needs. Due to this reason, there is no before undeleting operation available.

Hope it answers your question.